# Program error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a simple program to check a number to see if it is prime or not. I am having the user provide the number to check. But, I keep getting the following error when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 6, in <module>
    if num % test == 0 and num != test:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The following is my code:

```
num = input('Please choose a number between 2 and 9:')
prime = True 

for test in range(2,10):

    if num % test == 0 and num != test:
        print(num,'equals',test, 'x', num/test)
        prime = False

if prime:
    print(num, 'is a prime number!')
else:
    print(num, 'is not a prime number!')
```

I am using Python 3. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to understand why my program isn't running properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: in Python 3 `input()` always returns text so you have to convert `num` into `int` - ie. `num = int(num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 `input()` always returns string so you have to convert `num` into `int` - ie. `num = int(num)`.

Now `num % test` means `some_string % some_int` and Python treats it as string formatting. It tries to use `some_int` as argument in string `some_string` but it can't find special place for this `some_int` and you get error.

BTW: https://pyformat.info

Comment: Thank you! That seems like an obvious thing that I must have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Because `input()` returns a `str` object, `num` holds a string instead of an integer. When using the modulus operator on a string, Python assumes that you are trying to do [c-style string formatting](https://pyformat.info/), but finds no speical formatting characters in your string, and raises an exception. '

If you want python to correctly interpret your program, you need to convert `num` to an `int` object instead of a `str` object:

`num = int(input('Please choose a number between 2 and 9:'))`